# call method when ImageView image is changed

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView which displays a webcam-frame from an webserver. This is done with help of an external library ([UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper))

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(room1webcam, "http://couka.no-ip.biz/webcam/cam.jpg", R.drawable.webcamplaceholder, 3500);
```

Since this is done asynchronously, I don't know how to make sth happen after the download is complete. Is there an method which is called by the ImageView when it's changed?

Sth. like the  XML-Tag

```
android:onClick="amethod"
```

Something like

```
android:onUpdate="anothermethod"
```

would be awesome

I found the

```
protected void drawableStateChanged ()
```

on the [ImageView documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#drawableStateChanged%28%29). Is this what I need? And if it is, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overloaded version of `setUrlDrawable()` that accepts a callback, thus you can do something like:

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(room1webcam, "http://couka.no-ip.biz/webcam/cam.jpg", R.drawable.webcamplaceholder, 3500, new UrlImageViewCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url, boolean loadedFromCache)
    {
        // here, you can do something after the image is loaded...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this library uses `setImageDrawable()` interface for setting downloaded image. You can create custom `ImageView` and override `setImageDrawable()` function. When it gets called - it means this lib is done downloading

Comment: Thx for your answer. Could you give me an example on how to do that? Sry I'm quite a newbie in Java :]